# Retrieving secret from HashiCorp Vault in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, hashicorp-vault, hashicorp

I am trying to retreive hashicorp vault secret and use it in jenkins pipeline. I managed to connect to hashicorp vault, but pipeline fails to retreive the secret saved in vault.

Pipeline output:

```
Started by user admin
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withVault
Retrieving secret: my.secrets/data/dev
Access denied to Vault Secrets at 'my.secrets/data/dev'
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withVault
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Pipeline:
key heslo exists in my.secrets/data/dev path

```
node {

    def secrets = [
        [path: 'my.secrets/data/dev', engineVersion: 2, secretValues: [
            [envVar: 'value', vaultKey: 'heslo']
      ]]     
    ]

    def configuration = [vaultUrl: 'http://10.47.0.235:8200/',
                         vaultCredentialId: 'b0467c75-24e4-4307-9a35-f7da364f6285',
                         engineVersion: 2]
  
    withVault([configuration: configuration, vaultSecrets: secrets]) {
        sh 'echo $value'
    
    }
}
```

my jenkins-policy.hcl file for approle method to access vault from jenkins:

```
path "my.secrets/data/dev" {
    capabilities = [ "read" ]
  }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: That `vaultCredentialId` looks a little strange. Can you you double check that is the ID you specified in the Jenkins credential plugin for this credential? Can you also confirm the Jenkins credential `kind` is `Vault App Role Credential` and is configured correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "data" from the "path" definition:

```
path: 'my.secrets/dev'
```

You must use the "data" in the policy path but not when retrieving the secret.

Comment: thank you for your answer Marcelo, unfortunately it did not help

Comment: There's something wrong with this path. Is it really named "my.secrets"? The defaud name is "secret" or "kv" (depending of the version).

Comment: output of vault read sys/mounts //////////////
my.secrets/    map[accessor:kv_a9b312dd config:map[default_lease_ttl:0 force_no_cache:false max_lease_ttl:0] description: external_entropy_access:false local:false options:map[version:2] seal_wrap:false type:kv uuid:c632275e-a5e9-91b9-1ab7-eb37e488b2fe]

Comment: Everything is correct, is the error message the same (Access denied to Vault Secrets at 'my.secrets/dev')? Maybe there is something wrong with the Approle credentials.

Comment: I made sure that everything is correctly set up. When I change the path in policy from "my.secrets/dev" to asterisk "*" everything works correctly